# Visual Studio 2008 Crystal Reports - Horizontal Reporting

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports

Is there a way to setup a crystal report horizontally so that I would have my groupings span across instead of vertical?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the Details - section expert and check "Format with Multiple Columns". Then you can also include groups in that "Layout" tab that just appeared.

Comment: This comes pretty close to what i want.  Just need to figure out how to keep the groups in the same column instead of bleeding over into the second column.  THanks!

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this effect:

```
Group Header
    Record 1     Record 2    Record 3
    Record 4     Record 5    Record 6
```

We had to manually organize our data like this:

```
    Column 1     Column 2    Column 3
```

And then we assigned numbers (0 to row count - 1) to each record.  If the record mod column count was 0, update the first column.  If 1, update the second column.  Etc.

As far as I know, there is no other way to do it.